# Crystal Reports can not give good Image quality at print time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, desktop-application, crystal-reports-2010

I work on one C# desktop appication. In that I use `Crystal Reports`. In it there are one header and in header I put one static `.jpeg` image file. When I get report at that time the image in header is not display in good quality. `But the original is in good dpi and also in good quality` than also it display like below image.
[image]

There are any solution for it?

Comment: Property of the Crystal Report as "Retain Original Image Color Depth" to be enabled. I hope this can help some one else as well.

Comment: Yes, setting that should work `
    1.Files -> Options
    2.Select "Reporting" Tab
    3.Select "Retain Original Image Color Depth" and "OK"
`

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, you can find that image setting under Crystal Reports -> Report -> Report Options...

Answer (score 0):

The crystal report documentation provide additional steps to improve image quality

https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/30407084-c51d-2b10-1f81-813488350e6f/Printing%20and%20Exporting%20Image%20Resolution%20with%20Crystal%20Reports%20and%20Crystal%20Enterprise.pdf

This web page explains what the words: BitMapMagnifDenominator
BitMapMagnifNumerator mean

https://knowledge.designmanager.com/support/solutions/articles/22000201385-quality-of-images-and-or-company-logo-is-poor-when-view-on-screen